# Global inline formula breaks configuration

Tags: amsmath, inline

How I can configure inline formula breaks globally without changing original formulas? What package can help me?
I saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode), but the trick with comma does not work.

**UPDATE**

The formulas look like

```
\( (B_{r+1,1}, C_{r+1,1}), \dots , (B_{r+1,m_{r+s}}, C_{r+1,m_{r+s}}), \dots , (B_{r+s,1}, C_{r+s,1}), \dots , (B_{r+s,m_{r+s}}, C_{r+s,m_{r+s}}) \)
```

Comment: You might want to give us some clues as to what your inline formulae look like. There is very little customisation possible. TeX never breaks inline formulae inside `{ }` groups so if you have lots of grouped terms, aome change to the original markup may be necessary, otherwise it should already break at infix operators without needing to be configured.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Related Question: [Writing an equation in a new line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/writing-an-equation-in-a-new-line/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You would need to play with the values a bit to get it looking nicer, but basically you need to add a `\penalty` (`\linebreak[0]` in LaTeX) to add additional break points and then add stretchable glue elsewhere so that the formula can stretch to get a breakpoint at the end of the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oldcomma}{\mathpunct}{letters}{"3B}
\let\olddots\dots
\def\dots{\hspace{0pt plus .7em}\olddots\hspace{0pt plus 7em}}
\mathcode`\,="8000
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`,\active
\gdef,{%
\oldcomma
\@ifnextchar\dots{%
\penalty0 %
\hspace{0pt plus .2em}%
}{}}
\endgroup
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\noindent aaa \( (B_{r+1,1}, C_{r+1,1}), \dots , (B_{r+1,m_{r+s}}, C_{r+1,m_{r+s}}), \dots , (B_{r+s,1}, C_{r+s,1}), \dots , (B_{r+s,m_{r+s}}, C_{r+s,m_{r+s}}) \) bbb

\end{document}
```